# Main Word in the centre of the vega word cloud

Tags: vega-lite, word-cloud, vega

Is there a way to have one particular word as Main Word in the centre of the vega word cloud?

Here in the example - https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/word-cloud, we can see that the 'VEGA' word is highlighted to a larger text. However, it is not always guaranteed to place in centre.

I understand that the cloud is formed based on random function and it is generated.

Wanted to know if there is any way so that one particular word can be fixed to centre and apply the random configs to the other words surrounding it.

I did go through the documentation but did not find any. Please let me know if there is something as such and I missed it in docs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is far from good, just to throw a fuzzy idea.
VEGA can be transformed to centre by appending this to `wordcloud` transform:

```
 {
   "type": "formula", "as": "x",
   "expr": "datum.text=='VEGA' ? 400 : datum.x"
 },
 {
   "type": "formula", "as": "y",
   "expr": "if(datum.text=='VEGA', 200, datum.y)"
 }
```

But I wonder if it is possible to moves away the surrounding words...

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-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-IFWw+btU1LHxRhzFq8zamJQq6iDKXeLm+zWPnneS3c0uB9oPgxb7ojPJoENPQScAYSjt2Gd5oD1O4hxwO7RkN+CwJp4UFyXKV0So-WAOXT4aGVvEljm3dQhHTkd3McIFECzCbG8gxKN28Ndf6wizZdz6evk5xbJO8RiDYEw1jUfo8QmdiwXAuwwnec06zsd5HZPQtwkQuwnej7ml-jlai6QNOUIrs8ILOWQcoirARMBaAEeJdDKH+HQEi2Z166SfP0Y6uoWQPSNL4R2A4GCjSukwcGsAJTZ2dp-PEshlCkHLMuE8EgGys0aNANCxwmBsE1FrH4cA8SWyCNgvE+9IaknJG5ci0RYRWXVHQE8ZwY48zevzLhBMwhSzuOGPSi4syZX1DAQ4ABrSqFgrIGXXk0Rokc2oMBtOwd01tY53BtG6R8KYbLMM1HMAAzFw16BhyhNGvtocQEg8R7hkfHQWwsEDMxAKzPa7NKLxzxAAGUYgLE8FQ7yZiHAcMIa8Z69DxhKFIHgjDtXDt1W2fV64+k-svKmcEGxxMSf8VcG1VRLlbkgRolIn4ZMOOo3+nh4KyysOg6pup9SGhPrpfSXCE6HnXHQW2dgQR4OdhWOEcpYjtxiggVRNBD5WUxPQ2ESAhaxgkamfxRJulZPKdY2mDYACq0YjgvjDp1TeA0ZEPnOv05BWsoQnxIosHqDZQyyKQAkpJfsrhAtttYaK8REjI1ptk+4XUWl5wLrqChMtISXGhGCd4kYPS9QYtbHGJo0SARMY5D42DkUViaKYNCttbhJDBB7aFtMYTLH6J6Rw5sdTZXGT4JhConlWCuh3Jo+dC7tHePINFAKIKB3unqRcN84hMCauQk+yUOnqCfmYWgUA-q8z4BCxpsz2FxCQAXFSahlVgIgEA0y-LjjBEktYRiTtPjpx2tix0zoT5Gs8LGRCZ5jLPP-pjWIyh5AXjiLSxQ1E4hQHVoeN2NDtCguSsjJIz0UHsgma-H0xTOqlKjO8ep3rAVcpzLMqE00zgVNcCWMs-VMLJVCtGZk4gGD9BSHkl8iBvlQFQqNRctCsoTBMLYf41b-j0ABkDZ24MMZQxZDDfS8rEYpR5FdGwFxGWUTLRHL6fVnF-3TYIgCLazi8o7LIJcMVVzpjposBmY0pjHEPWeDuURxA4LIO8BwbAM2jjAvYcQ2iAK1spBkAAujIZGVJ7EzFAFtGIgwDTYNwM4T0kgZBdSuLIQYn9MgQWjIMcxNpMhRGwLEDQIBOgAB0WO6AAOQIeAK4qQABfTISQST6EMBAQYHEaAAB9+jSblLJ2BkmGSSbQpJkeqmGoQHU0cK4pBNNynMJJ-TDVDMjz06Zq4HwTMaZ0woST8A7Nkgc5pk8SILOSYJnAOzsQvNHB8wpugkmYGBcXG56icnqIIEk9RLuUWyi+YiyRXTinpbJdPMltg6XIvHkbbF6wsXnCxZCLFnLfRAuacUYp5cimNmSb9LV-84h6tgjs0gUgLXnPtJaxKsgknmy9bYLZxosh+vNeyKAxT5gTDDYJpN4b-9JM4am+piomBAscci0ZjjwQvMcc0x53bwWDsMi255sLJ21ttc22147bWzttZoBx4bm3hvwEe+517w3jvDbO8Nh743Nvjde+N-b43jvjbO+N6w4gOOrcUdD1buhlzw+q8EZHToIBo9a3qGHLXZDI+bAofHEgcdDeR-oMns3kcKKpx2PSeOcf-wZ6cfxq3Fv09W9spIyPRiYAO-QZwR2OyC4F85jZfObxwEF9jzTx4xcy5gHKA7HZOPlck6cQravTS1YLoFyzBh6sQWMmrzTuGfipdGKpyzBWtWSbdIpiRavmE6-RqpFK9XMAMj1IFoSsXl0wF6w1Zrfo3Sea-p6R3slPN+gxFFjLPtDzKZwIniQ-XdCNaaOp1bKf6J65gsp003mXcZ6TSmwrjWlSeYl4V7bsvGuy5rwruz9I1fjdOHJy9knub+4+HAXQ0mDCefTEkVTpexAyd-ZJ-xk-9cs9U+IC0qm0-ub6J5sQ+XGsYQyzBOTG4d-HL26pabTpQF8RAHxqQGG5RYfQPYhymRlyDFFKMTIs8yPOH7ZQW4qCAC83+ON+AAFEABxTQDjbQAAfm0EKG0Aqk6DxCqAEHeBKG0AQIQ06AAD90COJwZmwEAOIBIAAqbQVxPiBDM-C-IYK-AYG-REO-GQB-dABka8TAF-FkAcQYTqDiIuD-L-TAX-f-YA0A94AANlqGIOKFPz4wQykJkGgEgjEy6B6BX2wx3gMEyEw2oJAAMCNDsEyFwNdzQFAHI3QFxmfyIysim0GF4PIJADXWoNmAAGJZABAkAABOAAJnyEyAcOEIEHcKgFcMKG8NcNcVcIEFcIAHYQBpCkMQAdEFDuhKDr8hh7pMh48EBDC2hhgrDNwbChV5BMi1VYhMjrDUBQBiNLCTDUjz8QAtg3xMiZ0phsMijFAbCmBlwrgmhqDQBGjNC7BK4EhQQoAbCupQFMi5Dn90ADQzBWjzCSMrDqiajzEi5uiQBRiTAAB5KIUKLaBoyYaggARj4xqI7BgkyPWK2O+F2LKJAF6JaEoAEGOJqJQwgDQ0UKSM0JE1kFMHMFI1kP5RmCKBKBqEKFiNKPKIsNIyqNQRsMhD+FWIqKhKyI-yfwGBqIRFeEGBpBswdWdgADk4Aph3hNBlBdCiMJBMBvwHAETIS39MAP8cNMT0SKSppmDzjaT0BuDwkmCVsRiKSqS4AOZRR7CDj3CpABBhDYj6h0E0B3Dz9L9kjb84R78FCQAWRWD2DOT39wleD+DACQCwDICQSYDFIP91T5SPjBglSUB6DVS5QNTWj0BOCuTP97o9TBCON3h3CxCXS5RJCYi+MgA)

Comment: Though the word VEGA is at the centre it is overlapping the other words.